# Notification code disappears automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

When I receive the notification I would like it to automatically disappear and have to upload manually I, Thank you in advance.

Here I attach the code, in which I create the notification. What I want to happen is that when I receive the notification, I get off, I can see it on the screen, and after a few seconds I go up alone without having to interact with it.

```
    public void notificacion(String label, String autor,String destino) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifica = new 
       NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable) getResources()

                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).getBitmap()))
                .setContentTitle("tittle")
                .setContentText(label)

                .setAutoCancel(true);


        Intent intnot = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intnot.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intnot.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intnot.putExtra("Destino", destino);

        PendingIntent intnotpend = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intnot, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notifica.setContentIntent(intnotpend);

                   notifica.setFullScreenIntent(intnotpend, true);

        notifica.setContentIntent(intnotpend);


    }

        NotificationManager notyman = (NotificationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notyman.notify(10, notifica.build());
     }
```

Comment: Can you explain, "What I want to happen is that when I receive the notification, I get off, I can see it on the screen, and after a few seconds I go up alone without having to interact with it." ?

Comment: When I get a push notification, it shows me on the screen but until I do not upload it does not disappear the push notification. What I want is that when I receive the notification, after a few seconds disappears from the main screen.